# Android Firebase Phone authentication with Firebase AuthUI

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase AuthUI in my project. I want to detect the OTP automatically for Phone Authentication. I referred the docs and added `SafetyNet` in my gradle like this

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.1'`

Even after this its still using `reCAPTCHA verification` by opening browser. What else do I need to add to implement SafetyNet and detect otp automatically

I'm using FirebaseUI as mentioned in [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui)

Answer (score 0):

Add app's SHA-256 fingerprint to your firebase app from settings [settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/general/)

if haven't done yet. And in the Google Cloud Console enable the [Android DeviceCheck API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com) for your project.

for more information [visit here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)